# Manipular respuesta json API en PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

Estoy realizando una petición por el método `POST` a una `API` desde `PHP` y este me devuelve un `JSON`, sin embargo al tratar de manipular esos datos no me deja, he intentado decodificarlo pero al realizar esto me devuelve **true** o el valor **1**, me podrían indicar como puedo manipular esa respuesta o de que otra manera puedo realizar la petición a la `api`, actualmente estoy conectándome con `curl`.

```
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/json";


$url = 'http://miapi.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$data =  array(
    "hash_key"        =>  '123456',
    "datos"           =>  array(
          "id"   =>  "12233",
          "fecha_ini" =>  "01/10/2019",
          "fecha_fin" =>  "29/10/2019"
    ),
);

$json = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  'POST');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$result = json_decode($output);
var_dump($result = json_decode($output,true)); 

print_r($output);
print_r($result);
```

Gracias

Comment: seguro que esa es la url?

Comment: Deberías verificar si no hay error en la petición, para depurar puedes poner algo así: `if (!$output) { var_dump( curl_error($ch) ); } else { //usar $output }`

Comment: Lo de la url por temas de seguridad no lo anexe ya que es una api privada, esta es la respuesta que obtengo    php:78:string '[ {"id" : "","cod_entidad" : "01","nom" :..........   apartir de aqui como puedo manipular esa informacion, es decir obtener los valores de esa respuesta y poder a su vez tambien recorrer los resultados, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás recibiendo los datos así más o menos:

```
[ 
            {"id" : "1","cod_entidad" : "01","nom" :"Pedro"},
            {"id" : "2","cod_entidad" : "04","nom" :"Marta"}
]
```

Significa que estás recibiendo un objeto del tipo JSON array.

Para leerlo, hay dos formas.

### 1. Como objeto JSON

Si cada JSON dentro del array tiene la misma estructura, o sea, todos tienen una propiedad `id`, `cod_entidad` y `nom`, lo puedes leer como objeto JSON usando las propiedades para acceder a los datos:

```
$mJson=json_decode($output);
foreach ($mJson as $item){
    $str="{$item->id} - {$item->cod_entidad} - {$item->nom}".PHP_EOL;
    echo $str;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1 - 01 - Pedro
2 - 04 - Marta
```

### 2. Como array

En PHP puedes convertir el JSON a array, si le pasas el parámetro `TRUE` a `json_decode`. De ese modo queda un objeto que puedes leer mediante la notación `foreach ($elArray as $k=>$v)`.  Esta forma es útil cuando pueden venir claves dispares en los objetos, o cuando nos interesa imprimir el nombre de cada clave.

```
$mArray=json_decode($output,TRUE);
$str="";
foreach ($mArray as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $k=>$v){
        $str.="$k : $v".PHP_EOL;
    }
    $str.=PHP_EOL;
}
echo $str;
```

**Salida:**

```
id : 1
cod_entidad : 01
nom : Pedro

id : 2
cod_entidad : 04
nom : Marta
```

### Notas:

1. Cabe decir que la lectura adecuada de un JSON dependerá de su estructura. Si dentro tiene  por ejemplo otros objetos o tiene arrays, el código de adaptarse para alcanzar de forma adecuada esos datos.
2. Los datos de salida de ambos casos son tomados de una respuesta hipotética, cuyo contenido aparece al inicio de la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias A.Cedano